# How can i have component render without App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I’m trying to use vue-cli for app, but i wonder can i use component without using App.vue ?
Here component is shown in html but when i click the button, the testFunction in component is not called  but in html the button "click here" is showing

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    

  </head>

  <body>

   <h1>hi</h1>

    <div id="app">

      <MyComponent @my-event="testFunction"></MyComponent>

    

    </div>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

    

  </body>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11" defer></script>

  <script  src="main.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

MyComponent.vue

```
    <div class="child" @click="$emit('my-event')">

click here

     </div>

 </template>

 

 <script>

export default {

  name: 'MyComponent',

  props: {

  }

}

</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('MyComponent',MyComponent);

new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  beforeCreate() {

    console.log('Vue instance beforeCreate!');

  },

  created() {

      console.log('Vue instance created!');

  },

  

  mounted() {

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')

    .then(response => response.json())

    .then(json => this.todos=json);

  },

  

  components: {

   MyComponent

  },

    

  data: {

      todos:null,

      data:null

  },

  

   methods: {

       testFunction:function(){

         console.log("clicked");

       }

    },

  

  render:h => h(MyComponent),

}).$mount('#app')
```

My Question:

1. here testFunction in MyComponent is not called . but i see MyComponent is $emit
   and i dont use App.vue
2. is there way to register component, without render:h => h(myComponent)? and without $mount("#app")? 

   3.there is [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app error in console

Comment: *is there way to register component, without* - how do you expect it to be used then? This sounds like XY problem. If you have a specific problem to solve, please, describe it.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible with the default configuration of vue-cli. If you want to import the component globally or only into a specific module then that is entirely possible, but what you are asking isn't possible. If you'd like to read more about local and global imports then read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html).

There is a potential workaround though. You could create a second div to mount the application into, and then use the `MyComponent` component as the Base component for that mounting `div`. However, you will NOT be able to share data directly between the two Vue applications, and this behavior was used to be reserved for Modal insertion; however, nowadays the correct way to do this would be by via teleporting elements. You can read more about teleporting elements [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html)

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import App from './App.vue';
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue';


createApp(App).mount('#app');
createApp(MyComponent).mount('#app2');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="app2"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the solution is to use App.vue with different options like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div >
      <div id="AdminTemplate" v-if="this.$route.meta.layout == 'AdminTemplate'">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    <div id="NormalTemplate" v-else>
        <router-view />
    </div>
  
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And in the router

```
{
    path: "/admin",
    name: "AdminVue",
    component: AdminVue,
    meta: { layout: 'AdminTemplate' },
  }
```